# Objects colors and line art disappear in 2D Animation wokspace

Tags: 3d-view

I was trying to do a 2d animation in loop with a tutorial last night, it's my very first time in blender.

I drew some grease pencil objects, colored them and they also have lineart. But in some point, when I was at object mode, colors suddenly disappeared and I just see the lineart. I guess I clicked something wrong but I don't know what I did.

When I try make another object and color it, the same happens. And if I change modes from the panel next to the overlays.

[image]

I see only colors and not the lineart.

Answer (score 1):

Your 3D view is set to *Wireframe* mode. You can change it to any other mode (*Solid*, *Material Preview*, and *Rendered*) in the topright of the editor. You can also use the shortcut <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to toggle between Solid / Wireframe mode.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer but i've tried that and this time i see only colors without the lineart. Lines are only visible in Wireframe mode... Any more ideas? :/

Comment: Go to the material properties (red icon on the bottom right), and see if your material has "Lines" checked